# Selenium NoSuchElementException always returns True

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, boolean

```
class Errors:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def No_Subject(self):
        try:
            x = self.webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="confirmModalBtn"]')
            x.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I am importing this definition into second class

```
        self.error3 = Errors.No_Subject(self)
        print(self.error3)
>>True
```

No matter what XPath I enter(for example I entered *data*), it returns True. Why this code does not properly work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what the `else` block actually does. Read [here](https://geek-university.com/python/the-try-except-else-statements/)

Your code is working correctly and returning True since there is no error that occurred. You can try passing a random id value in XPath and this should return `False`

Comment: It will also return true if any other exception is thrown. Selenium might be throwing a `WebDriverTimeout` exception if implicit waits are configured.